# Difficulty in understanding let and lambda usage in Scheme

Tags: c++, lambda, scheme, let

I am having hard time to understand the scope of the following code:

```
 (define (create-counter (x 1))
  (let ([count 0])
    (lambda()
      (let ([temp count])
        (set! count (+ x count)) temp))))
```

if I use:

```
(let ((c (create-counter ))) (+ (c) (c) (c) (c)))
```

the code work however if i tried with:

```
(+ (create-counter)(create-counter)(create-counter)(create-counter))
```

This does not work and give me a 0. Can someone please help me to understand this thoroughly? if possible, please compare to other language like C/C++ it would be easier for me to catch the hold of this. Thanks

Comment: You mean `(+ ((create-counter)) ((create-counter)) ...)`, right? With just one set of parentheses around `create-counter` I would expect an error because you're trying to add lambdas.

Comment: When you say "does not work and gives me a 0"... what do you expect the last expression to evaluate to?

Comment: @sepp2k: if just 1 parentheses, the function return the procedure definition am i correct?

Comment: @uselpa: I tried with 2 parentheses as sepp2k recommended and it returned value 0 only

Comment: again... what did you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(define (create-counter (x 1))
 (let ([count 0])
  (lambda()
   (let ([temp count])
    (set! count (+ x count)) temp))))
```

Translates to:

```
auto create_counter(int x=1){
  int count=0;
  return [x,count]()mutable{
    int r=count;
    count+=x;
    return r;
  };
}
```

A simple C++14 function returning a closure object.

When you do this:

```
(let ((c (create-counter ))) (+ (c) (c) (c) (c)))
```

It is:

```
auto c = create_counter();
auto r = c()+c()+c()+c();
return r;
```

It creates one counter, then runs it 4 times, returning 0 1 2 3 and adding to 6.

In this case:

```
(+ ((create-counter))((create-counter))((create-counter))((create-counter)))
```

It is:

```
auto r = create_counter()()+create_counter()()+create_counter()()+create_counter()();
return r;
```

Which creates 4 counters, and runs each one once.  The first time you run a counter you get 0.  So this adds to 0.

The closure object has state.  It returns a bigger number each time you call it.

Now you may not be familiar with C++11/14 lamnda.

```
auto create_counter(int x=1){
  int count=0;
  return [x,count]()mutable{
    int r=count;
    count+=x;
    return r;
  };
}
```

Is

```
struct counter {
  int x,count;
  int operator()(){
    int r=count;
    count+=x;
    return r;
  };
};
counter create_counter(int x=1){
  return {x,0};
}
```

with some syntax sugar.

I fixed what seems to be a syntax error in your original code.  I am no expert, so maybe I got it wrong.

As an aside, a briefer create counter looks like:

```
auto create_counter(int x=1){
  return [=,count=0]()mutable{
    int r=count;
    count+=x;
    return r;
  };
}
```

Comment: very thorough explanation. i grasp the idea bit better.

Answer (score 2):

When you call "create-counter", it creates a counter and then returns a procedure that refers to that particular counter. When you call "create-counter" four times, you're creating four separate counters; each procedure refers to its own counter. When you call "create-counter" once and then the resulting procedure four times, it's creating just one counter, and incrementing it four times.

It's a bit hard to compare this to C, since C and C++ are quite weak in the area of closures; it's not easy to return a function that's defined inside of another function.

The closest analog might be a "counter" object in C++; think of "create-counter" as the constructor for an object containing a single integer, and the resulting procedure as an "increment" method that increments the counter contained in that object. In your second example, then, you're creating four distinct objects, where in your first example, you're creating one object and calling its "increment" method four times.

Comment: Closures have syntax support since C++11, 5 years ago, which makes returning them easy.

Comment: @Yakk C++11 lambdas are not like Scheme closures. In Scheme, locations have "unlimited extent" and it's not possible to cause a dangling reference. Whereas in C++ lambdas, you have to say whether a free variable reference is by reference or value; the former can cause dangling references.

Comment: @chris That is just object lifetime.  In C++ automatic storage variables are defined to be invalid to access after a certain point: just a state change.  All scheme adds is forced free store allocation and garbage collection overhead: both are optional in C++. (Full mark-and-sweep style gc is hard in C++, but doable).  If you do not need shared state, you can simply take by value.  Regardless, in the OP's case, there is *nothing* going on that a simple C++ lambda does not handle with by-value mutable capture, as I have demonstrated in my post.

Comment: @Yakk Yes, C++ keeps adding features, it's true.